# JSON.load と JSON.parse の違いは何ですか？

Tags: ruby

Ruby の JSON モジュールには JSON を読み込むためのメソッドとして load と parse が用意されています。

両者は用途が殆ど同じように見えるのですが、何かしら大事な挙動の違いや使い分けがあるのでしょうか？　「こういうときはこちらを使った方が良い」というのはありますか？　パッと見では load の方が高機能に見えるのですが parse は何のために用意されたのでしょうか。

- https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/JSON.html#M_LOAD

  > 与えられた JSON 形式の文字列を Ruby オブジェクトとしてロードして返します。
- https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/JSON.html#M_PARSE

  > 与えられた JSON 形式の文字列を Ruby オブジェクトに変換して返します。

Comment: 同じ質問が[本家stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226402/whats-the-difference-between-json-load-and-json-parse-methods-of-ruby-lib)にもありました。複数の回答に要点が分散してしまっている感じなんで、どなたか日本語でまとめた回答を作成してくれないですかね。

Answer (score 7):

`JSON.load` は内部で `JSON.parse` を利用しています。そして、それぞれは目的が違います。

`JSON.parse` は、JSON文字列に対して、それを ruby の組み込み型で読み込むことを目的に実装されています。その挙動は、資料に依れば、基本的には [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)準拠の読み込み動作を行います。(例: NaN や Infinity は rfc に規定されていないので、読み込みエラーになる。これを `Float::NaN` などで読み込むためには、 `allow_nan: true` を指定する)

`JSON.load` は、もう少し汎用的なことを目的としていて、「ruby 的なオブジェクトを読み込む」ことができるように設計されています。具体的には、string だけではなく IO オブジェクトを引数にとったり、第2引数で proc を指定して任意の微調整を行えるようにしたり、 `create_additions` な規約に従い、 Hash ではなく任意の ruby オブジェクトを読み込みしたり、です。(その実、 `create_additions` は `JSON.parse` でも可能ですが、しかしデフォルトオプションでは off になっています)

```
class Foo
  def initialize(attrs)
    @attrs = attrs
  end

  def self.json_creatable?
    true
  end

  def self.json_create(attributes)
    new(attributes.reject { |k| k == 'json_class' })
  end
end

JSON.load('{"json_class": "Foo", "bar": "piyo", "hoge": "fuga"}')
# => #<Foo:0x00007fd3811f50c0 @attrs={"bar"=>"piyo", "hoge"=>"fuga"}>
```

また、セキュリティ的な観点でも違いがあります。 `JSON.parse` は例えば JSON での api 通信の読み込みにも使いうるように実装されており、そのために、何も考えずに任意の JSON をパースしても危険じゃないように、もろもろの設定値がデフォルトに設定されています。一方、 `JSON.load` は主にシリアライズ・デシリアライズが主目的のため、プログラマにとっての利便性が優先されています。(信用できないデータはデシリアライズしては、そもそもいけないよね、という原則論があるような気がします)

具体的に、このように `JSON.parse` と `JSON.load` でデフォルトが異なっているオプションには、 `create_additions`, `allow_nan`, `max_nesting` があります。

---

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17226402/3090068